# Cross compilation for ARM board?

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, android-kernel

I was trying to cross compile a simple hello program as stand alone application which will run as binary on arm board, but I am facing problem while running hello binary on arm board.

Below are steps I have followed : -

**make  ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- hello**

Now *hello* is successfully build when I check file type of hello  using file command : -

***$file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x68edccf6dba1057774e3d7853914578e53889a75, not stripped***

When I push this binary in Android Linux phone under /data folder

1- adb push hello /data

2-chmod 777 /data/hello

3- ./hello (but here hello is not able to run)

Can somebody give me hint what mistakes I am making while compling or running binary on phone.

I am getting strange error messages while running program as shown below : -

root@xxx:/data # ./hello

./hello

Open failed: No such file or directory

1|root@xxx:/data # sh hello

sh hello

hello[1]: syntax error: '☺üê4┤¡♣☻♣4' unexpected

1|root@xxx:/data #

Comment: Do you have an arm compiled libc too?

Comment: @Joe I am not  able to understand your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android requires [Position Independent Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) for native libraries. Try adding **-pie -fpie** flags to the compiler. Another issue can be the one described by @Joe. On Android, there is a [Bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) standard library. If your "hello" program doesn't use any standard call, you can try compiling without standard library (using the toolchain provided in NDK):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -pie -fpie -nostdlib hello.c -o hello
```

Better option however is to create a simple **Android.mk** file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= hello.c
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS:= test
LOCAL_MODULE:= hello
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

And use it inside already [set up Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html) by issuing [mm](http://elinux.org/Android_Build_System#Helper_macros_and_functions) command.

If you however want to use standard library and for some reason don't want to use Android.mk, then you can download (and build) all Android sources and pass the includes paths to the gcc (example):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -pie -fpie --sysroot=<path_to_android_sources>/out/target/product/<product>/obj/
-I<path_to_android_sources>/bionic/libc/arch-arm/include/ -I<path_to_android_sources>/bionic/libc/include/
-<path_to_android_sources>/bionic/libstdc++/include/
```